# im getting a keyerror when trying to access a dictionary where the key does exist

Tags: python, dictionary, keyerror

I'm building this app where I can see live cricket scores using this API. When I'm trying to access the teams name its giving me a key error which doesn't make sense as the key does exist.

```
import requests

api_key = ""  

url_currentmatches = f"https://api.cricapi.com/v1/cricScore?apikey={api_key}"
response = requests.get(url_currentmatches)
result = response.json()

match_number=-1
amount_of_matches = len(result["data"])
while True:
    match_number += 1
    if match_number == amount_of_matches:
        break
    else: 
        name1 = result["data"][match_number]["teamInfo"][0]["name"]
        name2 = result["data"][match_number]["teamInfo"][1]["name"]
        

        important_countries = ["Pakistan","New Zealand","Australia","Sri Lanka","South Africa","West Indies","England","India"]
        for country in important_countries:
            
            if  name1.find(country) != -1 or name2.find(country) != -1:
                print("name matche: " + name1,name2)
                print("We have the result:", name1," vs ",name2)
                print(country)

       

            else:
                pass
```

Here is a snippet of the data of one of the matches:

```json
{
    "apikey": "",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "50f2cc52-c119-4323-b320-d004b8262761",
            "name": "Northern Cape vs Mpumalanga Rhinos, 11th Match",
            "matchType": "test",
            "status": "Northern Cape won by an innings and 96 runs",
            "venue": "Diamond Oval, Kimberley",
            "date": "2023-12-20",
            "dateTimeGMT": "2023-12-20T08:00:00",
            "teams": [
                "Northern Cape",
                "Mpumalanga Rhinos"
            ],
            "teamInfo": [
                {
                    "name": "Mpumalanga Rhinos",
                    "shortname": "MPR",
                    "img": "https://g.cricapi.com/iapi/49-637991993271802283.webp?w=48"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Northern Cape",
                    "shortname": "NCAPE",
                    "img": "https://g.cricapi.com/iapi/61-637991981464151764.webp?w=48"
                }
            ],
            "score": [
                {
                    "r": 185,
                    "w": 10,
                    "o": 42.1,
                    "inning": "Mpumalanga Rhinos Inning 1"
                },
                {
                    "r": 502,
                    "w": 10,
                    "o": 153.4,
                    "inning": "Northern Cape Inning 1"
                },
                {
                    "r": 221,
                    "w": 10,
                    "o": 62,
                    "inning": "Mpumalanga Rhinos Inning 2"
                }
            ],
            "series_id": "e3bd2125-82e2-4841-a097-c681d46c7a60",
            "fantasyEnabled": true,
            "bbbEnabled": false,
            "hasSquad": true,
            "matchStarted": false,
            "matchEnded": true
        }]}
```

The data could have some unclosed lists or dictionaries as I removed a lot of the matches and singled it to one, so please ignore that but all the other matches have the same format.

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
Exception has occurred: KeyError
'teamInfo'
  File "D:\Window Widgets\Dump.py", line 42, in <module>
    name1 = result["data"][match_number]["teamInfo"][0]["name"]
KeyError: 'teamInfo'
```

Comment: Please regenerate your api_key with a new one.  Never include any credentials in your posts.  Also, with regards to your error,  check if ```result["data"][match_number]``` has exactly the same format your expecting because it seems like not all matches actually use the expected format.

Comment: as far a your suggest ive realised that i was using the wrong link i think that should fix it thanks for the help

Comment: @Saif1708 starting a loop from -1 looks weird. Start from 0 and move `match_number += 1` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

first try to print(result["data"][match_number]) and check if is there a key like that,
second remember since you are incrementing the 'match_number' in the beginning of your loop you never touch the result['data'][0]